# Ruby NoMethodError - undefined method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, controller

I have this function in my controller

```
def create
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    @tweet.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|

        if @tweet.save
            format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "hello" }
            format.js   { render action: 'create', success: true, location: @tweet }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'show' }
            format.js   { render action: 'create', success: false }
        end

    end

end
```

the form is set to remote: true so this is my **create.js.erb**

but I got his error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `tweet_url' for #<TweetsController:0x007f8de60e4b58>):
  app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

any idea why is this error displaying?

Comment: Can you please post your routes file?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with `location: @tweet` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try changing this to to this if you want to render create.js.erb

```
format.js   { render action: 'create', success: true, location: @tweet }
```

to simply this

```
format.js
```

Comment: i think my answer will solve the problem. but also can you show me your create.js.erb